# Forum with LDAP integration?

Tags: ldap

Is there any popular forum software (installable, not hosted), that has LDAP integration for users?

Ubuntu server, Python would be nice but not required, authentication only for now, although profiles would be nice at a later point

Comment: This probably makes more sense on the [Webmasters SE site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What platform (language, server, etc)? Do you just need LDAP for authentication or do you want to pull profiles from it?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek Or webapps.stackexchange.com, or even ubuntu.stackexchange.com - I figured LDAP is fairly technical, so SO might be the best place to start ... but I'll give the others a go - delete this question if i get a better answer elsewhere!

Comment: SE duplicate post here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/forum-with-ldap-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/forum-with-ldap-integration) from [mar10](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1703/mar10) on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com):

> Have you had a look at phpBB3? You can
>   read about their default auth settings
>   [here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Communication-settings-in-phpBB3-65420.shtml).